# How to Set Firewall Rules on a GCP VM with Multiple NICs?

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform

GCP allows a VM to have multiple NICs, but firewall rules are governed by TAGS which unfortunately are attached at the VM level, NOT at the NIC level. So how would I configure totally different firewall rules on each NIC, given that tags only work on the VM level? Also in my case each NIC is in a separate VPC.
Google's documentation is less than helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud does not support attaching multiple NICs to the same VPC. Each Firewall rule is associated with one VPC.

> So how would I configure totally different firewall rules on each NIC,
> given that tags only work on the VM level?

Create separate Firewall rules for each VPC.